# Cannot access embedded PostgreSQL database of Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm having problems accessing the Cloudera Manager UI because of problems with the embedded PostgreSQL database.

The web UI shows me:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /cmf/home. Reason:
>
> ```
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection Caused by:
> ```
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection (...)

This seems to be because of what I find in `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/db.log`:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "scm"
```

I've tried deleting `/etc/cloudera-scm-server-db/db.*`, and `/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/`, and restarting the `cloudera-scm-server-db` service, but to no avail.

The weird thing is that I CAN access the database using:

```
psql -U scm -p 7432 -h localhost -d scm
```

with the generated password from `/etc/cloudera-scm-server-db/db.properties`.

I can also access using user `cloudera-scm` with the generated password in `/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt` without problem.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: i have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

[The password in generated_password.txt is for different user i.e. cloudera-scm](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cm_ig_embed_pstgrs.html#cmig_topic_5_7__section_myy_czd_zm)

1. Run below command and enter the password found in  `/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt`

   `psql -U cloudera-scm -p 7432 -h localhost -d postgres`
2. Run `\l` to determine the database and owner names:
   `postgres=# \l
                                        List of databases
   Name    |    Owner     | Encoding | Collation  |   Ctype    |         Access privileges

   -----------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------
   amon      | amon         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   hive      | hive         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   nav       | nav          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   navms     | navms        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   postgres  | cloudera-scm | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   rman      | rman         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   scm       | scm          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | 
   template0 | cloudera-scm | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | =c/"cloudera-scm"
                                                              : "cloudera-scm"=CTc/"cloudera-scm"
   template1 | cloudera-scm | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | =c/"cloudera-scm"
                                                              : "cloudera-scm"=CTc/"cloudera-scm"
   (9 rows)`
3. Set the password for an owner using the \password command. For example, to set the password for the scm owner, do the following:

   `postgres=# \password amon
   Enter new password: 
   Enter it again:`

This way you can change password of scm user.

PS. sorry for poor formatting.